# How to output data from crPlots in R package car?

Tags: r

As part of a larger multiple regression analysis, I'm using the R package `car` to make partial regression plots using `avPlots` and partial residual plots using `crPlots`.  I then need to output the data from `avPlots` and `crPlots` in *.csv format (i.e., I need to output the plotted data for use in another plotting software).

I am able to output data from `avPlots` using the following code:

```
require(car)
model <- lm(log(y)~log(x1)+log(x2), input_data)
avPlots(model)
x1_data <- avPlots(model, ~x1)
write.csv(x1_data,"~\\x1.csv")
x2_data <- avPlots(model, ~x2)
write.csv(x2_data,"~\\x2.csv")
```

However, when I attempt the same for crPlots:

```
model <- lm(log(y)~log(x1)+log(x2), input_data)
crPlots(model)
x1_data <- crPlots(model, ~x1)
write.csv(x1_data,"~\\x1.csv")
x2_data <- crPlots(model, ~x2)
write.csv(x2_data,"~\\x2.csv")
```

My output is a *.csv file containing a single zero.  Can anyone tell me how to properly output the data from crPlots?

Comment: What data from `crPlots`? The help page says it returns NULL.

Comment: Hi DWin,  the data I'm looking to output are the data plotted in the partial residual plots that are prodecud by crPlots.  I'm able to output the plotted data for avPlots, but not crPlots.  Thanks!

Comment: The code is open source. Look at the function and decide what you want to have returned.

Comment: Hello DWin, I took a look at the source code.  I'm not sure, but I think I want to return the '.x' and 'partial.res[,var]' from the code for crPlots.  (I'm not positive, but I believe those are plotted as the x-y points, which is what I am trying to output as a *.csv.)  Do you know how I might output those?  When I type '.x' or 'partial.res[,var]' in R after running 'crPlots', it just says "object not found".  Thanks!

Comment: I keep saying _the_crPlots_function_returns_NULL_. It you want to change that function so that it returns something you will need to hack the code.